# Limit running time of API call in CLI/C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-cli

I want to limit the time I am waiting for a response on an API call, in a C++/CLI ref class.

I've seen the [following code](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/05/28/how-to-set-a-maximum-time-to-allow-a-c-function-to-run-for/) in C# that looks what I'd like:

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return LongRunningMethod();
});

bool isCompletedSuccessfully = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));

if (isCompletedSuccessfully)
{
    return task.Result;
}
else
{
    throw new TimeoutException("The function has taken longer than the maximum time allowed.");
}
```

How can I get this code "translated" into CLI/C++? It looks like Task.Run does not work straight away.

For the record, my "LongRunningMethod" is something like:

```
            bool my_client::CanContactServer()
            {
                bool isAvailable = static_cast<bool>(m_p_client->contactServer());

                return isAvailable;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ /CLI does not support lambdas, but still you can pass delegate into `Task.Run` method. Your code will look like this:

```
// I suppose you have an instance of my_client initialized somewhere
my_client^ client = gcnew my_client(); 

Func<bool>^ f = gcnew Func<bool>(client, &my_client::CanContactServer);
Task<bool>^ task = Task::Run(f);

bool isCompletedSuccessfully = task->Wait(TimeSpan::FromMilliseconds(3000));

if (isCompletedSuccessfully)
{
    return task->Result;
}
else
{
    throw gcnew TimeoutException("The function has taken longer than the maximum time allowed.");
}
```